# UML decision node syntax for using objects in guard condition

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

Given an object `array`, an instance of some arbitrary class `Array`, which for this purpose has an attribute `length`.

How can I model an UML activity diagram, that, at some point, uses `array.length` in an control flow statement, i.e. in guards of a decision node.

```
array = getArray();
if (array.length > 5)
    save();
else
    waitForData();
```

I know that the guards of the used decision node would be `[array.length > 5]` and `[array.length <= 5]`. But I am not sure how I can integrate this with the object flow present in activity diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML does not specify how the guards should be described. It only requires it to be a logical expression i.e. one that evaluates either to true our to false.
You can use a natural language, any programming language or OCL.
The statement you've used is absolutely valid.
Additionally you can put a status of an object on an object node, e.g. [length > 5]

Comment: I also just read that **natural language contracts** are perfectly acceptable in UML.

Comment: @mike the purpose of OCL / precise languages is that they are machine-consumable and don't introduce ambiguity. If your target audience is humans, then natural language can be good enough.